# Create JSON using GSON with a colon as part of a field's name

Tags: json, gson

I've created a set of classes (pojos) that need to be transformed into json.  because i have a constraint that json field names adhere to a certain format, i've settled on gson as my library of choice, as it allows for annotations of field names.

so, i have json field names like `asset_type`, `preview_image_thumbnail`, etc.  along with that, any metadata fields must have the format, `metadata:<metadata-field-name>`.

so, what this comes down to is that my `metadata:tags` and `metadata:site` annotations will not be transformed by gson, since they are not valid json field names, according to gson, at least.

all works well, except for those darned metadata field names.  my goal is to have output like the following:

```
{
  "name": "Test Remote Asset",
  "description": "test-remote-asset",
  "asset_type": "remote_asset",
  "duration": 172360,
  "stream_urls": {
    "flash": "http://www.test-site.com/videos/a-video.flv",
    "iphone": "http://www.test-site.com/videos/a-video.3gp",
    "ipad": "http://www.test-site.com/videos/a-video.3gp",
    "source_file": "http://www.test-site.com/videos/a-video.mp4"
  },
  "metadata:tags": "tag1,tag2,tag3",
  "metadata:site": "test-site"
}
```

here is the exception i get when attempting to transform my class to json:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: metadata:tags is not a valid JSON field name.
```

and here is the class i want to transform:

```
public class RemoteAsset {

/** The video's name **/
private String name;

/** The video's description **/
private String description;

/** The video asset type **/
@SerializedName("asset_type")
private String assetType;

/** The video's duration, in milliseconds **/
private long duration;

/** The video's thumbnail preview URL **/
@SerializedName("preview_image_url")
private String previewImageUrl;

/** The video's OpenCms Structure ID **/
@SerializedName("external_id")
private String externalId;

/** The video's various streaming URLs **/
@SerializedName("stream_urls")
private StreamUrls streamUrls;

/** The video's tags, coma-separated **/
@SerializedName("metadata:tags")
private String metadataTags;

/** The video's host site **/
@SerializedName("metadata:site")
private String metadataSite;

public String getMetadataTags() {
    return metadataTags;
}

public void setMetadataTags(String metadata_tags) {
    this.metadataTags = metadata_tags;
}

public String getMetadataSite() {
    return metadataSite;
}

public void setMetadataSite(String metadata_site) {
    this.metadataSite = metadata_site;
}

public RemoteAsset() {

    this.streamUrls = null;
    this.assetType = null;
    this.previewImageUrl = "";
    this.metadataSite = "";
    this.metadataTags = "";
    this.externalId = "";
    this.description = "";
    this.duration = 0L;
    this.name = "";
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getAssetType() {
    return this.assetType;
}

public void setAssetType(ASSET_TYPE asset_type) {
    this.assetType = asset_type.getTypeName();
}

public long getDuration() {
    return this.duration;
}

public void setDuration(long duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getPreviewImageUrl() {
    return this.previewImageUrl;
}

public void setPreviewImageUrl(String preview_image_url) {
    this.previewImageUrl = preview_image_url;
}

public String getExternalId() {
    return this.externalId;
}

public void setExternalId(String external_id) {
    this.externalId = external_id;
}

public StreamUrls getStreamUrls() {
    return this.streamUrls;
}

public void setStreamUrls(StreamUrls stream_urls) {
    this.streamUrls = stream_urls;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("RemoteAsset [name=").append(this.name)
            .append(", description=").append(this.description)
            .append(", assetType=").append(this.assetType)
            .append(", duration=").append(this.duration)
            .append(", previewImageUrl=").append(this.previewImageUrl)
            .append(", externalId=").append(this.externalId)
            .append(", streamUrls=").append(this.streamUrls).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that those can't be mapped directly to Java variables because you can't have a colon in a variable name. You need to use the Gson `@SerializedName` annotation. The following works at least in Gson version 2.2.2:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    String json = "{\"some:field\":\"foo\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    MyClass mc = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);

    json = gson.toJson(mc);
    System.out.println(json);
}

class MyClass
{
    // String some:field;  <- You can do that!
     @SerializedName("some:field")
     String someField;
}
```

Output:

> {"some:field":"foo"}

Comment: yea, i know that well enough, but according to gson, i can't have a colon in the annotations, either.  i've edited my original question to include the class i want to transform to json, using gson.

Comment: I don't know what version of Gson you're using, but the above example I posted is runnable, and produces the output I posted. It does not throw that exception. Also copy/pasting your class into my IDE, Gson has no problem with it. This is with the current Gson 2.2.2

Comment: well, that was it - i was using 1.7.1.

i appreciate your help, brian, thank you!